# How does Vec<T> implement iter()?

Tags: rust

I am looking at the code of `Vec<T>` to see how it implements `iter()` as I want to implement iterators for my struct:

```
pub struct Column<T> {
    name: String,
    vec: Vec<T>,
    ...
}
```

My goal is not to expose the fields and provide iterators to do looping, max, min, sum, avg, etc for a column.

```
fn test() {
    let col: Column<f32> = ...;
    let max = col.iter().max();
}
```

I thought I would see how `Vec<T>` does iteration. I can see `iter()` is defined in `SliceExt` but it's implemented for `[T]` and not `Vec<T>` so I am stumped how you can call `iter()` from `Vec<T>`?

Comment: I sometimes feel that I am asking something that's super obvious ^^ That really helps to narrow down my line of investigation so I will now look into Deref! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Indeed, as fjh said, this happens due to how dereference operator functions in Rust and how methods are resolved.

Rust has special [`Deref`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Deref.html) trait which allows values of the types implementing it to be "dereferenced" to obtain another type, usually one which is naturally connected to the source type. For example, an implementation like this one:

```
impl<T> Deref for Vec<T> {
    type Target = [T];

    fn deref<'a>(&'a self) -> &'a [T] { self.as_slice() }
}
```

means that applying `*` unary operator to a `Vec<T>` would yield `[T]` which you would need to borrow again:

```
let v: Vec<u32> = vec![0; 10];
let s: &[u32] = &*v;
```

(note that even though `deref()` returns a reference, the dereference operator `*` returns `Target`, not `&Target` - the compiler inserts automatic dereference if you do not borrow the dereferenced value immediately).

This is the first piece of puzzle. The second one is how methods are resolved. Basically, when you write something like

```
v.iter()
```

the compiler first tries to find `iter()` defined on the type of `v` (in this case `Vec<u32>`). If no such method can be found, the compiler tries to insert an appropriate number of `*`s and `&`s so the method invocation becomes valid. In this case it find that the following is indeed a valid invocation:

```
(&*v).iter()
```

Remember, `Deref` on `Vec<T>` returns `&[T]`, and slices do have `iter()` method defined on them. This is also how you can invoke e.g. a method taking `&self` on a regular value - the compiler automatically inserts a reference operation for you.

Comment: Great answer and I understand how it works now. I've just implemented iter() for my `Column` struct by just implementing Deref for it. :)

Comment: Yeah, one of the nicest things of this feature is that it can be used by arbitrary code, not only in the standard library :)

Comment: Deref also allows the coercion of `&Vec<T>` to `&[T]`, so this will compile: `let s: &[u32] = &v;`